# Join In queryover in NHibernate

Tags: sql, vb.net, nhibernate

I am using NHibernate. I want to use join on queryover,  try following code but this gives error,

```
session.QueryOver(Of Messages)()
  .Where(Function(x) x.UserID_Messages.Username.Contains(msgfrom))
  .And(Function(x) x.Message.Contains(msg))
  .And(Function(x) x.MsgDate >= startdate)
  .List
```

But this error = Unrecognised method call: System.String:Boolean Contains(System.String)
And if i try this query

```
session.QueryOver(Of Messages)
  .JoinQueryOver(Of Users)(Function(x) x.UserID_Messages)
  .WhereRestrictionOn(Function(x) x.Username).IsLike("%" & tosearch & "$")
  .List(Of Messages)()
```

This result empty, even record is there in database. Please guide what am I doing wrong, or what is correct way to achieve this. Thanks

Comment: Are you sure your searched term always ends with an "$"?

Answer (score 0):

The `.Contains` method, is a .NET method, which is not translated into SQL statement when using `QueryOver` syntax. The second approach, with `QueryOver` native method `IsLike` is what we need. To be sure, that we will end up with a SQL like this:

```
username LIKE '%the searched value%'
```

we should use the built in `MatchMode`

```
.WhereRestrictionOn(Function(x) x.Username).IsLike(tosearch, MatchMode.Anywhere)
```

*See the [MatchMode](https://github.com/nhibernate/nhibernate-core/blob/master/src/NHibernate/Criterion/MatchMode.cs) class definition*